# How can I connect the lowest int to the correct name in my DB, Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working with lat, lng between different locations and gathering the distance between two different points. 
I succesfully get out the distance between different points where I currently sort them by the closest distance (in kilometer).

What I however am struggeling with is getting the correct name to the correct distance (that is being made out of the two different lat, lngs that is in the same row as the name).

So one row in the db looks like this (I have like 10 different rows with different locations with their correct latitude, longtitud):

Lat -----------   Lng -------  Name

45.032 --14.323112-----Iceland

I then take that Lat, Lng and with my code below I get the users current position lat, lng and i then compare the distance between the users current lat, lng position and out of it i have an int cointaining the kilometer to the closest distance.

How can I now connect that distance with the correct Name?

```
    string thename;

    string areaLat;
    string areaLng;

    double storeLat;
    double storeLng;

    double thedistancebetweenobjects;      

    async void loadareas()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
        var position = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(10000); //using a plugin that gives me the users current lat, lng. 

        List <int> theInts = new List<int>();

        var getarea = await phpApi.getAreas(); //my db-callout

        foreach (var myitems in getarea["results"])
        {
            thename = myitems["Name"].ToString();

            areaLat = myitems["Lat"].ToString();
            areaLng = myitems["Lng"].ToString();
            storeLat = Double.Parse(areaLat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            storeLng = Double.Parse(areaLng, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            thedistancebetweenobjects = distance(position.Latitude, position.Longitude,storeLat, storeLng, 'K'); //so the users current position lat + lng, and then the lat (storelat), and lng (storelng) i get from the db.

            int someOtherInt = Convert.ToInt32(thedistancebetweenobjects); //converting double to int

            theInts.Add(someOtherInt);
        }

        int TheSmallestInt = theInts.Min();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TheSmallestInt);
        //I succesfully get the smallest int out. But how do I connect this int with the correct name from the db?
    }
```

And this is the function that takes the two different values of lat, lng and gives me the distance result in kilometer:

```
private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit)
    {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat2)) +
        Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.Acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == 'K')
        {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
        }
        else if (unit == 'N')
        {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }
        return (dist);
    }

    private double deg2rad(double deg)
    {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private double rad2deg(double rad)
    {
        return (rad / Math.PI * 180.0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string closest = string.Empty;
int dist = int.MaxValue;

foreach (var myitems in getarea["results"])
{
  thename = myitems["Name"].ToString();

  // do all of your calcs here

  int someOtherInt = Convert.ToInt32(thedistancebetweenobjects); 

  // for every loc, check if it is closer than the previous loc
  // if it is, save it's name.  
  if (someOtherInt < dist) {
    dist = someOtherInt;
    closest = thename;
  }

  theInts.Add(someOtherInt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using the Haversine Formula which in this case is the correct way I would do it.

What I would do is then loop around your list of locations until you get to the closest one

```
List<double> distList = new List<double>(); //Create a list to store distance values
List<cityLocations> locList = new List<cityLocations>();
distList.Add(50000000); // default huge distance to compare against
foreach (var city in cityList)
{
    //diff between longitudes
    double theta = (double)ci.longitude - (double)ll.longitude;
    //harversine implimentation
    double dist = Math.Sin(Utils.deg2rad(ci.latitude)) * Math.Sin(Utils.deg2rad((double)ll.latitude)) + Math.Cos(Utils.deg2rad(ci.latitude)) * Math.Cos(Utils.deg2rad((double)ll.latitude)) * Math.Cos(Utils.deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.Acos(dist);
    dist = Utils.rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    if (dist < distList[0])
    {
        //always keep 1 record in list
        distList.RemoveAt(0);
        distList.Add(dist);
        if (locList.Count > 0)
        {
            locList.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        locList.Add(new cityLocations { cityName = ll.cityName, latitude = ll.latitude, longitude = ll.longitude, country = ll.country });
    }
}
```

Not the prettiest or efficent way of doing it by all means

Comment: I made it work with Jason's solution! This seems to work good as well!